# CloudWatch Unified Agent: Additional property append_dimensions is not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I'm trying to add a custom dimension to my statsd metrics published to the cloudwatch unified agent. CW docs state that `append_dimensions` under the `metrics` section only supports `InstanceId`, `InstanceType`, `AutoScalingGroupName` and ignores others.

**CloudWatch Agent Configuration File: Metrics Secition:**

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Metricssection)

> append_dimensions – Optional. Adds Amazon EC2 metric dimensions to all metrics collected by the agent. The only supported key-value pairs are shown in the following list. Any other key-value 
>   pairs are ignored.
>
> "ImageID":"${aws:ImageId}" sets the instance's AMI ID as the value of the ImageID dimension.
>
> "InstanceId":"${aws:InstanceId}" sets the instance's instance ID as the value of the InstanceID >
>
> dimension.
>
> "InstanceType":"${aws:InstanceType}" sets the instance's instance type as the value of the >
>   InstanceType dimension.
>
> "AutoScalingGroupName":"${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}" sets the instance's Auto Scaling group name > as the value of the AutoScalingGroupName dimension.

The docs recommend adding `append_dimensions` directly to the section defining the metrics you wish to use a custom dimension.

**Adding Custom Dimensions to Metrics Collected by the CloudWatch Agent**:

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-common-scenarios.html#CloudWatch-Agent-adding-custom-dimensions)

> To add custom dimensions such as tags to metrics collected by the agent, add the append_dimensions field to the section of the agent configuration file that lists those metrics.

So I tried adding `append_dimensions` to the `statsd` section:

```
"statsd": {
  "service_address": ":8125",
  "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
  "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60,
  "append_dimensions": {
    "Environment": "${APP_ENV}"
  }
}
```

and I get the error:

> Additional property append_dimensions is not allowed

I have tried sending tags with my metrics as well and they seem to be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The AWS Docs says "On servers running either Linux or Windows Server, the metrics section includes the following fields: ... append_dimensions" and "If you want to append dimensions to metrics with arbitrary key-value pairs, use the append_dimensions parameter in the field for that particular type of metric."

So you can only add append_dimensions in metrics section or any particular metric field.

[Retrieve Custom Metrics with StatsD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-custom-metrics-statsd.html) says "There are three optional fields that you can add to the statsd section of the agent configuration file as needed", so clearly statsd doesn't support append_dimensions.